# PHP Counter: Incremental ID for each item in foreach

Tags: php, foreach, counter, increment

I have a foreach, I'd like to have an incremental id="X" (X starting from 1 to - say - 6 if 6 items are present) for every item.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
function blahblah(){
    $url = 'THE_URL_WHERE_I_RETRIEVE_JSON';
    $cache = './BLAH/'.sha1($url).'.json';
    if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 1000){
        $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache));
    } else {
         $jsonData = json_decode((file_get_contents($url)));
        file_put_contents($cache,json_encode($jsonData));
    }
    $result = '<div id="my_div">'.PHP_EOL;
     if(is_array($jsonData->data)){
        // Do the for each
    } else {
        // It wasn't an array so do something else
    }
     foreach ($jsonData->data as $key=>$value) {
        $title = (!empty($value->caption->text))?' '.$value->caption->text:'...';
        $location = (!empty($value->location->name))?' at '.$value->location->name:null;
        $result .= "\t".'<a href="'.$value->images->standard_resolution->url.'">BLAHBLAH</a>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    $result .= '</div>'.PHP_EOL;
     return $result;
}
echo get_instagram();
?>
```

For example I'd like that id="X" to be here `<a ID="" href="">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem in this just add 1 variable which will work as **counter**

```
 $i = 0;
 foreach ($jsonData->data as $key=>$value) {
    $title = (!empty($value->caption->text))?' '.$value->caption->text:'...';
    $location = (!empty($value->location->name))?' at '.$value->location->name:null;
    $result .= "\t".'<a id="'.++$id.'" href="'.$value->images->standard_resolution->url.'">BLAHBLAH</a>'.PHP_EOL;
 }
```

Comment: np. Notice preincrementation in this code :) it will firstly add value to `$id` then return it

Answer (score 1):

If there's a reason to don't use for loop, use counter variable

```
$c = 1;
foreach($data as $item) {
   // code
  $c++; //increment the counter at the end of loop
}
```

You can freely use $c inside your foreach loop after that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$idx = 1;
foreach ($jsonData->data as $key=>$value) {
        $title = (!empty($value->caption->text))?' '.$value->caption->text:'...';
        $location = (!empty($value->location->name))?' at '.$value->location->name:null;
        $result .= "\t".'<a id="'.$idx++ .'" href="'.$value->images->standard_resolution->url.'">BLAHBLAH</a>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use may use a counter for this

```
    <?php
    function blahblah(){
     $url = 'THE_URL_WHERE_I_RETRIEVE_JSON';
    $cache = './BLAH/'.sha1($url).'.json';
      if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 1000){
      $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache));
    } else {
     $jsonData = json_decode((file_get_contents($url)));
     file_put_contents($cache,json_encode($jsonData));
    }
    $result = '<div id="my_div">'.PHP_EOL;
     if(is_array($jsonData->data)){
        // Do the for each
    } else {
    // It wasn't an array so do something else
    }
    $i=1;//use as counter
    foreach ($jsonData->data as $key=>$value) {
    $title = (!empty($value->caption->text))?' '.$value->caption->text:'...';
    $location = (!empty($value->location->name))?' at '.$value->location->name:null;
    $result .= "\t".'<a '.'id="'.$i.'" href="'.$value->images->standard_resolution-   >url.'">BLAHBLAH</a>'.PHP_EOL;
  $i++;
}
$result .= '</div>'.PHP_EOL;
 return $result;
}
  echo get_instagram();
?>
```